# localStorage - clear() or removeItem()?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Should I use `clear()` to obliterate everything in `localStorage`, or should I just manually `removeItem()` the ones I've set on that particular site (which is easy enough to keep track of)?

I ask because I don't want to end up wiping out users' `localStorage` if they have other values set.  I'm testing this in localhost and noticed that by using `clear()`, everything I'd set previously in other projects was wiped out.

EDIT: I should have mentioned that I know localStorage is domain-locked.  I'm running a site that follows this structure:

```
public-html
(localStorage)
--project1
----files
--project2
----files
--project3
----files
```

Where each file uses it's own separate localStorage variables.  If I `localstorage.clear()` inside project2, project1 and project3's settings will be lost as well.

Comment: Not sure what the question is here. You're saying you can't use `clear` so...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

localstorage is keyed to an origin.  So if all of your projects are running on localhost, then you'll wipe all of your values when you use `clear()`, and the only safe method is individual removal.

In a production environment, each project should have its own domain and `clear` should be safe.

So it's a question of knowing what else is on the current origin.  If you control everything on the current origin and don't mind wiping it all, `clear()` is the best choice and was designed for that purpose.  If there are other parts of your code using localstorage or other projects hosted on the same origin then you will want to be more selective and use `removeItem()`.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a lone domain for every one of my projects - I simply couldn't afford that.  I'd like to keep everything under my own personal 'portfolio'-esque website, with subfolders containing each of my separate, different projects.  Thank you though, looks like `removeItem()` is the way to go!

Comment: @Jaxo if you have a different subdomain for each project `clear()` would still work

Answer (score 5):

`clear()` clears everything on the current origin (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). Using `clear()` on example.com will not affect the localStorage for example2.com. It is clearing data for all projects on your computer because all of the testing files that you have are on the same origin (`http://localhost` or `file:///C:\`). Therefore, it will be fine to use `clear()`

Answer (score 0):

**`Clear() Method`**

1. Will wipe out everything from your localStorage
2. Doesn't take any argument

**removeItem() Method**

1. will only remove those localStorage items which you reference as an argument.
2. To make **removeItem** work you must need to pass in an argument. For example:

removeItem("list") will only remove this The "list" key items

// **For better understand code below**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="clear-method">Clear Method</button>
    <button id="removeItem-method">RemoveItem Method</button>


    <script>
        const clearMethod = document.getElementById("clear-method");
        const removeItemMethod = document.getElementById("removeItem-method");

        // declaring arraay for localStorage
        const computer = [
    {
        Brand: "Asus",
        Model: "Unknown"
    }
];

const phone = [
    {
        Brand: "Realme",
        Model: "Unknown"
    }
]

// setting up items on localStorage
localStorage.setItem("computer", JSON.stringify(computer));
localStorage.setItem("phone", JSON.stringify(phone));

        clearMethod.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        localStorage.clear();
        })

        removeItemMethod.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            localStorage.removeItem("phone");
        })
    </script>
   
</body>
</html>
```