# Remove my site from cache when a visitor goes to a specific page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, caching, browser-cache, meta

Is there a way to clear all my sites data from a users browser when they visit my contact us page or register page? I need this to happen one way or another to update their info site wide. So when they visit the home page it can personalize some data. Browsers seem to ignore the new data after i obtain it from the form. I want the pages cached for visitors who don't contact us, to help with the load speeds. It is a wordpress site, no plugins please.

Stack users never disappoint! thanks in advance Everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps these two other post's may shed some light on this for you. Hope it helps.
For localstorage.clear() & localstorage.removeItem():

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/15486641/4812515

Possibly right some logical into your function to implement this type of method.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/11530896/4812515

Comment: i have lots to learn. i'm more looking for what someone else used to accomplish this on their site. Script and all to use while i learn this in the mean time.